# my for is running twice when it was supposed to run only once

Tags: javascript

I have a for where there is a request to upload an image. It should run only ONE time, but it is running twice and thus uploading the same image twice.
I can't find the error, in my view it has the correct parameters

```
function uploadImage(itemsUpload) {
    requestImage
      .get(`images/url`)
      .json()
      .then(response => {

        let number= 1;

        for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {

          if (itemsUpload.length > 0) {
            const URL = response.url
            const newURL = URL.replace('https://store-tst-marketplace.s3.amazonaws.com/', '')
            const img = itemsUpload[i]["file"]
            let blob = new Blob([img], { type: 'image/png' })

            request
              .put(`images/upload/${newURL}`, { body: blob, headers: { "content-type": blob.type } })
              .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
              })
          }
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Why are you using a `for` in the first place if the body is only supposed to run once?

Comment: Why in the future it may be an array of images

Comment: Hmm, it's kind of impossible for us to test this exact code. Do you have an example where this happens even without those requests in the middle?

Comment: are you sure `uploadImage()` isn't getting called twice?

Comment: There's no way it could be looping twice. I suspect the `uploadImage()` function is being called twice. Add a `console.log()` call before the loop to confirm.

Comment: actually, I auditioned and is calling twice. Thanks guys!